# Java Beginner - Cannot find symbol- variable

Tags: java

Not really sure whats causing the error here, its when i enter a value in for String name upon creation of the item.

Any help would be appreciated, cause im pretty stuck at the moment

```
public class Item {
    double itemCode;
    String itemName;
    double itemPrice;

    public Item(){
    }

    public Item(double code, String name, double price){
        itemCode = code;
        itemName = name;
        itemPrice = price;
     }

    public String getCode(){
        return String.valueOf(itemCode);
    }

    public void setCode(double itemCode){
            this.itemCode = itemCode;
        }

    public String getFirstname(){
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String itemName){
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

    public String getPrice(){
        return String.valueOf(itemPrice);
    }

    public void setPrice(double itemPrice){
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        }

    public String toString(){
        return (String.valueOf(itemCode) + ": " + itemName + ", £" + String.valueOf(itemPrice));
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your code compiles fine. Can you show us how you are using it and what error you are getting?

Comment: No main method, no stack trace. No clue what the question is.

Comment: "Error: cannot find symbol - variable x" where x is what ive tried to put into the String name

Comment: Post the main method. There's nothing wrong with what you posted here.

Comment: Use [[edit]] option to include in your question code example which will let us reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to initialize this object will be

```
Item item = new Item(1.0d,"item",10.0d);
```

You cannot do it will look for a variable x

```
Item item = new Item(1.0d, x, 10.0d);
```

If you want the value to be x you should do

```
Item item = new Item(1.0d, "x", 10.0d);
```

or

```
String x = "x";
Item item = new Item(1.0d, x, 10.0d);
```